# Does visual studio 2008 pro has SP1 built-in?

Tags: visual-studio

I have to install SP1 Redistributable when using MSVC2008 pro?
I just would like to know because the project Im trying to compile requires it and I'm not sure if I should install it. I couldn't find answer on this question anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio can come with slipstreamed Service Packs, however you need to find this out, if your installation media says it's Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 then you have good luck, otherwise, once installed, go to Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio and there you will see if you already have the SP1 already installed.